# Save a select from another table in a CRUD application

Tags: laravel, crud

I have a `Categories` table and a `Gender` table. In the Categories form you can choose your gender, which comes from the `Gender` table.

The problem is that the option you choose doesn't show when you want to edit something. after you made the Category. However it does show in the database in the Categories `cte_gender_id` as an integer. (1, 2 or 3)

**This is my CategoryController:**

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$array_category_gender_id = array();
$gender_id = $category->cte_gender_id;

$genders = Geslacht::where("gen_id", $gender_id)->get();

foreach($genders as $gender){
$array_category_gender_id[] = $gender->gen_name;
}
```

**And the html:**

```
<label>Gender</label>
<select name="gender_id" class="form-control" id="gender_id">
    <option disabled selected value>Select a gender...</option>
    @foreach($genders as $gender)
        <option value="{{ $gender->gen_id }}" {{ ($category ? (in_array($gender->gen_id, $array_category_gender_id) ? 'selected' : '') : '') }}>{{ $gender->gen_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need relations https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: the Categories has a gender_id

Comment: did you set up a relation on the model and load it with ->with() or ->load?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: @hurnhu means you have to read documentation. all about relations explained there. you have to define relations and then you will be able to get your genders with categories

Comment: But everything works except showing the gender when you want to edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$category = Category::find($id);

$category_gen = $category->cte_gender_id;

$genders = Geslacht::where("gen_id", $gender_id)->get();
return view('your_view',compact('category_gen','gender'));
```

```
@foreach($genders as $gender)
@if($category_gen==$gender->gen_id)
        <option value="{{ $gender->gen_id }}" selected>{{ $gender->gen_name }}</option>
@else
option value="{{ $gender->gen_id }}">{{ $gender->gen_name }}</option>
@endif
@endforeach
```